# error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`. in Mac

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, react-native

I am setting up an Android development environment. However, there is a problem in the execution environment. I've already finished the configuration, but I keep saying I can't find the device. However, if you run the server and then run it in the Android studio, it will work normally. What's the problem?

**bash_profile**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_241.jdk/Contents/Home
export PATH=${PATH}:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export ANDROID_PATH=/Users/myname/Library/Android
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH/sdk/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH/sdk/tools/bin
```

But Error

```
$ npx react-native run-android


info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 864 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info Starting JS server...
/bin/sh: adb: command not found
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 5 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

> Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.

> Task :app:installDebug

> Task :app:installDebug FAILED
27 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 18 up-to-date
[adb]: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
[adb]: * daemon started successfully

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
[adb]: * daemon not running; starting now at tcp:5037
[adb]: * daemon started successfully

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:629:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/myname/AwesomeProject/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

Is there anyone who has the same problem as me?

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
> vim ~/.bash_profile
```

Add the following lines:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/myname/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_PATH/tools/bin
```

Save changes and restart terminal.

Run ADB and if you got following it will work.

```
> adb devices

List of devices attached

emulator-5554   device
```

Comment: I do not have a directory called `emulator` in `ANDROID_HOME`, I installed the sdk and android-platform-tools using brew

Answer (score 0):

If you already configured the `.bash_profile` check the `ANDROID_HOME` using `echo` and then you simply need to run your app with this command :

`source ~/.bash_profile && npx react-native run-android`

**UPDATE**

Pay attention to this : You should run `bash` shell **NOT** `zsh` shell to be able to run emulator.